# Facebook Pixel Stats GET / Reading

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Pixel on my website that is tracking events. I saw on the Ads Manager dashboard, that the pixel logs my events in a categorized way, i.e.:
PageView, ViewContent, InitiateCheckout, etc.

[image]

Although when logging stats, I include some extra parameters like the product_id maybe or other things, that way when the PageView is being logged, at least I will know which product_id it refers to.

The problem is that the Facebook Ads Dashboard doesn't show any of the extra parameters, it only displays the Count field.

[image]

After doing some research, I found this [link on Facebook Pixel Stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/facebook-pixel-stats/v2.5), where they claim:

> Use the Facebook Pixel Stats edge to get pixel statistics.

I tried using the **Graph API Explorer**, and even the iOS FB SDK for it ([API Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/stats)) they both return an empty data array:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I tried multiple parameter combinations, fields, and everything else to no avail.

If anyone knows whether I'm looking at the wrong place, or what not, **all I'm interested in is reading those "extra" parameters that I'm appending to every FB Pixel event I log**. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need specifing the parameters for it.
Example:

```
{fb_pixel_id}/stats?aggregation=url
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is displayed for a specific period of time in the past - I would say 24 hours. 
You can use paging at the bottom of the json response for going back in time: use the link provided in the content of the field 'previous', and you can step back day by day.